# stored procedure always returning one row result in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I  have a table like this in my sql server:

```
TransactID    Dtid     Sid

1086          5        4
1086          7         8
1086          4         3
```

i want to take corresponding name of Dtid and Sid from resepective table.so i created stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[PDTDamageFetch]
@Carid NVARCHAR(50)

AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @transid integer,@dtid integer,@sid integer,@Damage nvarchar(100),@side nvarchar(100)
select @transid= t.transactID from Transaction_tbl t where t.TBarcode=@Carid
select @dtid= tr.Dtid from TransactDamageAssign_tbl tr where tr.transactID=@transid
select @sid= tr.sid  from TransactDamageAssign_tbl tr where tr.transactID=@transid
select @Damage=dt.DtName  from DamageType_tbl dt where dt.Dtid=@dtid
select @side= ds.SName from DamageSide_tbl ds where ds.Sid=@sid
select @Damage,@side
end
```

then i executed my stored procedure passing corresponding carid..transactID of particular car id is `1086`       but stored procedure always showing one row of data..how i can replicate my issue..my

```
expected out put at this stage is:
```

### Damage     Side

```
scrtch    front
broken      Back
damged       side
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query instead of yours. You are just assining one value to a variable, and that's why you just get one row

```
SELECT * FROM Transaction_tbl  t
INNER JOIN TransactDamageAssign_tbl tr ON tr.transactID = t.transactID
INNER JOIN DamageType_tbl dt ON dt.Dtid = tr.Dtid
INNER JOIN DamageSide_tbl ds ON ds.Sid = tr.sid
WHERE t.TBarcode=@Carid
```

Comment: insted of selct * i given "SELECT dt.DtName,ds.SName" now i got exact out put

Comment: sorry i just to show you the exact query. I'm happy it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try table variables or temp tables to list all records.

The way you are trying, will always return the very last row of matching condition.

Comment: the #table or @table variable that you are saying will slow down the performance of the SP

Comment: Yes, You are right. In the first look I thought of some computations there. But its straight forward inner joins. Thanks.